# requestAnimationFrame() and setTimeout() - increased amount of frames per second

Tags: javascript

I make a simple game and I have problem - after game ends and you start new game animation speed increases (because I checked another options I know that amount of frames per second is much higher). Every time new game starts speed animation speed increases dramatically. Is that because of bad use of requestAnimationFrame? Why this happens?

```
function Game() {
     this.startGame();
}

_p = Game.prototype;

_p.startGame = function() {
    //game functions
    this.renderer.drawGame();
    this.update();
    this.handleCollisions();
    this.stats.overheat--;
    this.overheating();
    this.handleClicks();

    if(this.gameOver() == false){
        requestAnimationFrame(this.startGame.bind(this));
        //I tried do this in this way too:
        //setTimeout(this.startGame.bind(this), 20)
    }
};

_p.gameOver = function() {
    if(this.stats.chances < 1){
        var self = this;
        this.renderer.endGameScreen();
        soundManager.pauseAll();
        document.addEventListener("click", function(){
            self.stats.chances = 3;
            self.stats.scores = 0;
            self.stats.overheat = 0;
            self.startGame();
            soundManager.resumeAll();
        });
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Your end game processing adds a new click handler. Then when the next game ends you add another new click handler. After the second one ends you add a third click handler. A click will then call all of the handlers, starting multiple game loops at once. (Or so it looks to me.)

Comment: @nnnnnn I tried use clearTimeout() and that didn't work. Is there any other way to fix it?